# Pass array using ajax into controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is the code:
where arg is [1,2,3]

```
function filtersearch(arg) {
        var arry = [];
        arry = arg;
    debugger
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("getFilterActiveData")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { args: arry },
            tradition: true,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
            debugger
                side_menu(data.listdata.length, data.listdata, data.color);
            }
        });
```

Array value is not passed in controller

```
  public ActionResult getFilterActiveData(string[] args){}
```

shows null in args..any suggestion?

Comment: try add [FromBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute like  `public ActionResult getFilterActiveData([FromBody] string[] args){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try validate that the `arg` values are in the correct format and what data gets posted to the action method.

When I test with `filtersearch([1,2,3])` it binds the result correctly.

One correction: The parameter `tradition` should be `traditional`
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thats true..spell of traditional is wrong..thnx for ur reply :)